# Run GUI program without login

Tags: java, windows, selenium, automation, windows-7-x64

I have machine in which I have to run selenium tests without logging in system.
I can run them in background using something like this:

```
PsExec -i -u <Domain>\<User> -p <Password> \\<Computer> my_script.bat
```

(Script run 2 jar files, and when test begin they open browsers)

I need login and see test actually running (see open browsers).
How can I do this?

Comment: Would a remote desktop connection not suffice?

Comment: Unfortunately, the script launch initiates Linux.

Comment: Do you need to see the GUI while the selenium tests are running or is it enough to see the log files to check the current status?

Comment: I need to see open browser. Logs i see via Jenkins.

Comment: If you're using Linux, why not look into using tightVNCserver, running on your Linux box, and a VNC client viewer used from your Windows box?

Comment: The problem is that if I run the script remotely without logging I cant see it running when I login to system. But it running.
P.S. I use same credentials when I run script and when login.